# Error: Circular structure in "getInitialProps" result of page : Nextjs with apollo client

Tags: next.js, apollo-client, react-apollo

I am following this guide https://www.apollographql.com/blog/getting-started-with-apollo-client-in-next-js/ to try and convert an app to use nextjs getServersideProps and client side queries. The articles explains it very well how to approach each scenario but I am facing an issue with trying to pass the apolloClient to the apollo provider in _app.js. The main difference to the article is that to initialize the apollo client I need context to read req headers for authenticated state.

I get the error Error: Circular structure in "getInitialProps" result of page "/". https://err.sh/vercel/next.js/circular-structure and indeed inside apolloClient I can see circular structures which means the error makes sense..

How should I go about this? Any ideas / suggestions?

Inside getInitialProps :

```
 public static async getInitialProps({ Component, ctx }: any) {
    const apolloClient = createApolloClient({}, ctx);

    ...

    return {
      apolloClient,
      ...
    };
  }
```

where createApolloClient returns :

```
return new ApolloClient({
    connectToDevTools: process.browser,
    ssrMode: !process.browser, // Disables forceFetch on the server (so queries are only run once)
    link: ApolloLink.from([
      authLink.concat(
        ApolloLink.split(
          ({ variables }) => hasFiles(variables),
          createUploadLink({ uri: URL }),
          link,
        ),
      ),
    ]),
    cache: new InMemoryCache({
      // possibleTypes: introspectionQueryResultData,
    }).restore(initialState || {}),
  });
```

I can see that the apolloClient is returning fine, also have used it inside a getServerSideProps and it there works just fine. Only in _app.js this is happening.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you add the code for `getInitialProps` to the question please?

Comment: Hey! Updated with some code ;) thanks. Removing the apolloClient code from getInitialProps does make the error go away btw..so def it comes from there (also its visible while logging it)